# How to establish site-wide fields with my theme?

Tags: plugin-recommendation, cms

I have been searching high and low and cannot seem to find a plugin/implementation for wordpress which allows for site wide values to be set and used (in places such as header/footer).

Any help much appreciated

**EDIT**

Sorry I might not have been clear enough. What I am wanting to do is have fields which can be set in the backend and displayed site wide such as a phone number in the footer. Thanks

Comment: Finding a plugin is not a programming question, off topic for this site. http://wordpress.stackexchange.com

Comment: You can use text widgets for this, which would be both in one: You enter the text into the widget on your widgets screen in the backend and it will be displayed where you placed it. Is that an option for you?

Answer (score 3):

Just throw the values in your theme's functions.php file and use them in your other templates. This is a little too simple to warrant writing a plugin.